# SSIS Derived Column hangs

Tags: ssis, salesforce

I have an SSIS package whose ultimate goal is to retrieve attachments from Salesforce (using the Cozyroc Salesforce connector).
(Using MS Visual Studio 2013)

The connector appears to work fine.

I first read filenames from Salesforce and then try to build a path in a Derived Column so I can export the attachment to a local file.

However, the Derived Column step hangs. I simplified it to the point of not even using any of the fields I pull back from the source and it still hangs. The Salesforce Source finishes in a second showing 32 rows in the data viewer.

My Derived Column looks like this:

[image: Derived Column]

Would appreciate any advice - I haven't been working with SSIS very long.
Thanks.

Comment: I seem to have solved the problem - when I removed the data viewer from the data flow, everything went through lickety split. I was able to put the fields back into the flow and build a real derived column, too. Wish I could explain why the data viewer prevents the package from progressing.

Comment: The dataviewer pauses the dataflow so you can see it as a snapshot in time. When it pops up, click on the green play button or "detach" to let the flow run again.

Comment: Thank you - I know your comment doesn't answer my original question, but it does deserve  to be marked as one.